# Releasing a version of iOS app to a specific AppStore and availing the older to the rest

Tags: ios, app-store

Now I have a major feature to release and I want to see the impact of it on a specific app store. The question is, if I submitted the app to the store and approved it.

Would it kill all other instances on all stores and my app would be available on that one specific AppStore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to "soft launch" an update by itself via iTunes Connect (only new apps by choosing the available territories for sale).

If you change the availability of your app to one country, users would not be able to download/purchase/update your app anywhere else, which I guess is something you don't want.

But it's definitely something you can hard-code. (Question is, if you really want this/it makes sense)

Comment: That's what I had in mind. Just wanted to A/B test the app before releasing this huge change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so , since when releasing a new version it automatically remove the previous ones from the store , so the new and only version is valid for the territories you select.